# When I try that there will be a popup to do google authentication with firebase it does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

When I try to perform google authentication with firebase, neither the googleSignInWithPopup method works, nor with any other. I am following the instructions in the documentation and nothing appears
about this error.
It does not throw any error and all functions are called

this is the code I am implementing:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyBTtZRgAufHwkuth3Jo-pnTTKl1tBrK92o",
authDomain: "journal-react-redux.firebaseapp.com",
projectId: "journal-react-redux",
storageBucket: "journal-react-redux.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "189133948252",
appId: "1:189133948252:web:99aaaedf42fdb97243ed99"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


const db = firebase.firestore();
const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();


export {
    db,
    googleAuthProvider,
    firebase
}

export const startGoogleLogin = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(googleAuthProvider)
            .then(({ user }) => {
                dispatch(
                    login(user.uid, user.displayName)
                )
            });

    }
}

export const login = (uid, displayName) => {
    return {
        type: types.login,
        payload: {
            uid,
            displayName
        }
    }

}


const handleGoogleLogin = () =>{
    dispatch(startGoogleLogin);
}
```

this is all the code where it is used and declared for use.
PS: This app is made in react 17 with redux.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this code snippet? Also, make sure that Google Authentication is enabled in Firebase Console

```
export const loginUserWithGoogle = () => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

    return auth
        .signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then((result) => {
            return result.user;
        })
}
```

Then you can use this code in your actions

```
export const logInWithGoogle = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        loginUserWithGoogle()
            .then((user) => {
                // ... do something with user
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
}
```

Try to update your function to

```
const handleGoogleLogin = () => {
    return (dispatch) => { 
        dispatch(startGoogleLogin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i enable google authentication on console firebase but it's like nothing. I already tried to deactivate it and activate it again, change the project, the credentials but it remains the same. And if I tried what you put me but nothing did not throw any error or work.

Comment: Could you add a code snippet with the example of how you are executing the code?

Comment: if you print something before this line `firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(googleAuthProvider)`, is it being printer to the console?

Comment: yes, this is configuration on archive firebase.js: `  const db = firebase.firestore();
const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
export { db,googleAuthProvider,firebase}`  this is auth.js archive: `export const startGoogleLogin = () => { return (dispatch) => { firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleAuthProvider)
    .then(({ user }) => {
        dispatch(
                    login(user.uid, user.displayName)
                )
            });
    }
}` 
startGoogleLogin is called when the button is clicked with handleGoogleLogin as shown above in the question

Comment: I don't use the cdn, I am installing firebase in the project. The button triggers the handleGoogleLogin function when they click but never opens the login popup

Comment: you are using `signInWithRedirect` not `signInWithPopup`. Perhaps your browser is blocking opening a new tab? Try to rename to `signInWithPopup` instead

Comment: Thanks for the observation, although the error is the return of the startGoogleLogin function, I was testing it and the return function is not called, do you see something strange?

Comment: I have noticed one more thing, updated my answer with new solution. Notice that you were using dispatch but you have not provided it as callback function in `handleGoogleLogin`